# Javascript Sort Error with sort function possible simple fix

Tags: javascript, sorting

Probably a simple fix, The rest of the table is sorted excpet this part here 
(right at the top)
[image: picture of table problem]
The table will work now and again in the right order (data from source does not change) but is really dicey when it does or not

Ideas?

Sam

Heres the code

```
//first define a function
var sortTable = function() {
    $("#tableid tbody tr").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
        var dataA = $(a).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();
        var dataB = $(b).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();
        return parseFloat(dataA.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB.substring(
            1));
    }).appendTo('#tableid');
};
//include two files where rows are loaded
//1.js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'url1',
    success: function(json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results[i].section;
            var no = json.results[i].avalible;
            var price = json.results[i].price;
            var button =
                "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Compare</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tr  ><td>" + section +
                "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price +
                "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function() {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
        sortTable();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
//and here is the 2nd js file
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'url2',
    success: function(json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results[i].section;
            var no = json.results[i].avalible;
            var price = json.results[i].price;
            var button =
                "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>" + section +
                "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price +
                "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function() {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
        sortTable();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: The spaces before the decimal points are messing with the sort order, since you only apply `parseFloat()` to those values. `parseFloat()` will stop parsing at the space.

Comment: sorry where? i must be blind.

Comment: Between `£94` and `.99`, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting as to do with spaces but is also linked to your jquery selector.

As often, array are 0 index based in Jquery, then if you want to sort on your price your `2nd column (0-index based)` you need to do as below :

```js
var sortTable = function() {
    $("#tableid tbody tr").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
        var dataA = $(a).find("td:eq(2)").text().replace(/\s/g, "");
        var dataB = $(b).find("td:eq(2)").text().replace(/\s/g, "");
        return parseFloat(dataA.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB.substring(
            1));
    }).appendTo('#tableid');
};

var json = {results:[{price:"$12 .45"}, {price:"$13 .45"}, {price:"$12 .05"}, ]}
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
  var section = json.results[i].section;
  var no = json.results[i].avalible;
  var price = json.results[i].price;
  $("#tableid").append("<tr ><td>section</td><td>no</td><td>" + price);
  
}
sortTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid"></table>
```

`

Comment: Hi there Copy and pasted that straight in but the spaces are still there

Comment: the html is just a basic table. `<thead>` and `<th>` commands only.

Comment: `{"offset":0,"results":[{"price":"£89 .99","avalible":["1","2"],"section":"Standing"},`

Comment: doing the test myself, there are 2 problems in your code (spaces and array indexes)

Comment: How would i fix this?:)

Comment: Look at my sortTable function I replaced your `find("td:eq(3)")` with `find("td:eq(2)")` and remove spaces with the `.replace(/\s/g, "")`.